# "Server error" while hitting a URL from controller in SAP Hybris

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to practice SAP Hybris basic flow and while hitting the URL from the controller I am getting a "server error" as the response as shown below.
[image]

The controller looks something like this:

```
@Controller
public class NewCustomerController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/custid", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getCustomerNameFromCustId(@RequestBody final Model model){

        final List<NewCustomerData> nameList = newCustomerFacade.getCustomerNamefromID();
        model.addAttribute("nameList",nameList);
        return ControllerConstants.Views.Pages.NewCustomer.CustId;
    }
}
```

The JSP page "custid.jsp" looks something like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="" tagdir="" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Customer ID detail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This page displays the name of the customer based on customer ID</h1>
    <h3>The name of the customer is ${nameList}.<h3>
</body>
</html>
```

In the dao layer, when I evaluate the call to execute the query, I get this error:
[image]

Can anyone help me please what am I doing wrong? I am stuck on this since 2 days now.

Comment: Did you check the backend logs?

Comment: Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String de.hybris.training.storefront.controllers.misc.NewCustomerController.getCustomerNameFromCustId(org.springframework.ui.Model)]

Comment: You have "@RequestBody final Model model" in your function and when you try to get the url, the body missing. Maybe you can try it with postman to post some body.

Comment: [Request processing failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.exceptions.FlexibleSearchException: SQL search error - incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type VARCHAR to java.lang.Long, value: customer1 query = 'SELECT  item_t0.p_name  FROM newcustomer item_t0 WHERE ( item_t0.p_custid =1) AND (item_t0.TypePkString=? )', values = [8796147417170]] with root cause
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type VARCHAR to java.lang.Long, value: customer1

Comment: This is another error.

Comment: yes, the previous one is resolved. Can you help me with this? @mkysoft

Comment: Check your where condition. It look you are sending custid as long, but it is string. You need to add quote.

Comment: @mkysoft this issue is still not resolved. I need help.
SELECT {c.name} FROM {newcustomer as c} WHERE {c.custid} = '1000'. This is the query and "incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type VARCHAR to java.lang.Long, value: customer1" this is the exception thrown. Can you please help how to modify? or any information you need? In the Backoffice if I execute this query, I am getting the desired result as "customer1"

Comment: I didn't see customer1 column in your query. Maybe the error coming from a different part of the code or restriction. Can you try to SQL logging on flex? Maybe you will get correct query.